# Are page initiated ajax request cached invalidated when the Reload button is pressed?

Tags: jquery, ajax, caching, browser

What happens when you press a browser's reload button, and there are cached ajax calls executed on jQuery document ready?  Will you get a cached copy, or will cache be invalidated because Reload button was pressed.  Follow up question, will cache be invalidated for ajax calls made by user initiated actions on the page after the page has fully reloaded?

From personal testing on an app I am working on, hitting the reload button invalidates the cache for ajax calls made on the page.

I've looked for this information, and closest I've gotten is a cache FAQ on Mozilla Developer Network.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Caching_FAQ

It would make sense to me that the ajax requests would be made separate from the page reload, but as I mentioned from personal testing that does not appear to be the case.  For some background, I am using ASP.NET MVC with OutputCache set to Location = Client on the VendorList action.

Here are requests as recorded on the Chrome developer tools Network tab:

Requests with VendorList cached
[image: Cached Requests]

Requests initiated by Reload button, note VendorList not cached
[image: Reload Requests]

Vendor list non-cached request details
[image: Reload VendorList Request Details]

Comment: You only get a cached copy of static resources ( like js, css, img files ). Any other get/post request are made again.

Comment: The action method called by ajax is configured to use private cache.  However, reloading the page appears to invalidate the ajax request's cache.  This behavior is helpful for me, but I can't explain it or trust it will work in production and across browsers.

Comment: You need to check in browser console if the cache is persisted during postbacks. I don't see why the cache object would disappear on reload.

Comment: I don't know why either, but it seems to be the behavior.  Browser dev tool screenshots are included as proof.

Answer (score 0):

When you reload a webpage what happens is that Ajax calls are made again, all of them. Then, it doesn't matter if the page is cached or not, it creates all the ajax calls independently of that.

A good related tipo is to press Ctrl + F5 for reload if you want to avoid cached webpages.

Also, you can create server-side cached ajax calls if you need to save some resources for your server.

Comment: The ajax request caching not being affected by the Reload button makes sense to me, but it doesn't match up with my testing.